# Can I create a custom event for a change to a specific value on a select?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to create a custom event with jquery 1.7, but I'm just learning about custom event and the examples on api.jquery.com/bind are not enough.

I have a select but I need to fire some function just when the select is set to an specific value?

Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

on the onchange event

```
$('#selector').change(function(){
    if($('#selector option:selected').text()=="value wanted"){
        //do stuff
    }
})
```

Should work

Answer (score 1):

Bind your change event, when the DOM is ready:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#yourselector').change(function(){
        if($('#yourselector :selected').text()=="yourValue"){
            //do your action
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: Would the .val() really work? I had that tought too but in my research all exemples were using .text(), so I wrote it down as .text(). Would it work too with .val()?

Comment: You're right. It breaks after jquery v1.4.3.. I'll update my answer (and upp'd yours)